# How do i properly update information in a text file?

Tags: c#, io

I want to save some data in a text file like this:

```
Name = Frank
Age = 28
Registered = False
```

Now i want to read/update the Data contained in each row. For example I need to change the Name to "Tim", I have to find row Name and than replace the string after the "="

Im not quiet sure how to solve this properly and i couldnt find anything on Google that satisfied me

I tried to update it with the text.Replace() method but it only chances the string it actually finds.

I expect to read the correct data out of the row and replace it if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a wide variety of ways to do this. I'll contribute one of them (which I think is simpler to understand).

**Step 1:** Read the entire file into a string.

**Step 2:** Convert it to string.

**Step 3:** Process the string using simple methods like split and join.

**Step 4:** Overwrite the previous file with the processed string.

The code is below:

```
if (File.Exists(your_file_path)){
    string yourfile = File.ReadAllText(your_file_path);

    // Now the file is a simple string that you can manipulate using
    // string split functions.
    // For Example:

    // break by lines
    string[] lines = yourfile.Split('\n');
    foreach (string line in lines){
        if (line.Substring(0,4) == "Name"){
            // replace the necessary line
            line = "Name = Tim";
            break;
        }
    }

    // Join the array again
    yourfile = lines.Join("\n", lines);
    File.WriteAllText(your_file_path, yourfile);
}
```

Comment: This answer seems much easier, sometimes i fell stupid for forgetting that simple stuff like Split exists.... Thanks for teaching me, this is exactly was i was looking for!

Comment: @Crylia that's great. But I still recommend that you learn about JSON when you have the time. It's the industry standard for doing exactly the thing you're trying to do.

Comment: @Nirva For sure i will, but ATM im trying to learn asynchron programming and i dont wanna do too many things at once.

Answer (score -1):

Try to save the file in Json format. Like

```
{
   "Name" : "Frank"
   "Age" : 28
   "Registered" : False
}
```

Then read the file deserialize it to object by using Newtonsoft json
Then update your property(Name) serialize it to string again and then write again to the same file.
In this Approach very less chances of errors.

Comment: That's not the JSON format. Use colon (:) instead of equals (=).

Comment: I think i need to read myself into that before i can test it, but it sounds promising, thanks!